# Как получить строку с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть html-строка.

```
<....
    <div class="q_text">
    <div class="news-date-time">Валерия, Тула</div>
    <div class="news-date-time" style="font-size:11pt;">пищевая продукция</div>
    Текст</div>
<....>
```

На данный момент я использую регулярку `(?<="q_text">)[\W\w]*?</div>`. Однако он выбирает самое короткое совпадение.

```
 <div class="news-date-time">Валерия, Тула</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы он получал на 1 div больше? Чтобы получилось вот так

```
 <div class="news-date-time">Валерия, Тула</div>
        <div class="news-date-time" style="font-size:11pt;">пищевая продукция</div>
```

Comment: Может, лучше воспользоваться существующими решениями для обработки [html в php](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php)?

Comment: Никогда, просто никогда не пользуйтесь рагулярками для разбора HTML.

Comment: Обязательная [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю единственный путь - явно указать второй `</div>`

`(?<="q_text">)[\W\w]*?<\/div>.*?<\/div>`

`.*?` конечно можно усложнить для проверки внутренностей, но особого смысла не вижу.